# Possible to make a div come to a point at the top? Must be responsive

Tags: html, css

Hello I have been assigned a tricky task. I need to make a square div come to a point at the top. Basically it will look like a square div with a wide triangle at the top. See my screen shot below. The dark blue at the top is just another div stacked on top of the white div.

[image]

Ive tried doing a psuedo before element to create a triangle from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) and positioning it at the top of the square. It works but is not responsive. I need to make the triangle a width of 100% so it is responsive. When shrinking the screen it gets funky so I decided to not go this route because I dont want to create tons of media queries.

I am unsure how to accomplish this other than the psuedo triangle element I tried, which does not work for me because it is not responsive. Maybe an svg element, or a skewed div?

Any one have any suggestions? I dont necessarily need someone to type out  code to answer this for me. I just need someone to point me in the right direction and I can write the code myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've provided [a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0mxvzc4/2/) (change `15vw` to your preferred height for the triangle at the top).

---

## Explained

I have created a `width: 0; height: 0;` div at the top and set its border on the left and on the right to `50vw` (so it takes up the entire width of the window). Next, I set the bottom and upper borders to be of height `15vw` (my chosen height for the triangle - as stated, customizable).

I set all of the borders to be transparent aside from the bottom border, which we want to be seen. Then I set `margin-top: -15vw;` to push it to the top of the window (by using `transform` we would transform it post-reflow and would therefore leave whitespace at the bottom).